# How can I efficiently plot a graph where each node represents a point in euclidean space?

Tags: python, math, graph, plotly-python

I have an almost fully connected graph in python with roughly 3k nodes and 9M edges. Each node in this graph is represented by a point in R^3 and each edge represents the distance between them. I tried iterating through all of the edges and just plotting them with matplotlib using a 3d projection. Something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = len(network.positions) - 1, subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})


    for idx in range(len(network.positions) - 1): 
        x = network.positions[idx][0, :].numpy()
        y = network.positions[idx][1, :].numpy()
        z = network.positions[idx][2, :].numpy()
        ax[idx].scatter(x,y,z, alpha = .5, s=.01, label = "layer " + str(idx + 1), c='r')
        

        x = network.positions[idx + 1][0, :].numpy()
        y = network.positions[idx + 1][1, :].numpy()
        z = network.positions[idx + 1][2, :].numpy()
        ax[idx].scatter(x,y,z, alpha = .5, s=.01, label = "layer " + str(idx + 2), c = 'b')

        for idx_1 in tqdm(range(int(network.positions[idx].shape[1]))):
            for idx_2 in range(int(network.positions[idx + 1].shape[1])):
                x_1, y_1, z_1 = network.positions[idx][:, idx_1]
                x_2, y_2, z_2 = network.positions[idx][:, idx_2]
                ax[idx].plot([x_1, x_2], [y_1, y_2], [z_1, z_2])
```

However, this is terribly inefficient - because of the many calls to plt.plot. I need a way that I can do something similar but weight the color or transparence of each line by a corresponding weight.

Thanks,
Ameet

Comment: Just paint every pixel on the screen black - by the time you've plotted 9M edges that's what it will look like.  More seriously, if you plot your 3k points in R^3, why plot 'edges' to represent the distance between them when the distance between them is already represented by the, well, the distance between them ?

Comment: You could have been nicer about how you asked that... The point of the edges is the weight that mentioned towards the end - maybe that should be more clear. I want the weight to be represented as transparency, probably downscaled by several factors, so you'd only really see the weights that are somewhat large.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Ameet, plotting is not a useful option when you have 1000's of nodes/edges, leave alone millions. A better option is to decide on what you want to convey and then plot a sub-graph as needed.

Comment: I want to see if subnetworks (adjacent areas with high weights) exist - do you have an idea how I can do that? @RamNarasimhan

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but I think it requires discussion. I think you might see if cs.stackexchange.com has something to say about this -- I think the problem of visualizing highly-connected subgraphs might have some well-known approaches.

Comment: Yes, as @RobertDodier suggests, edit this question or post the new question about dense subgraphs to the CS StackExchange.

Comment: ok, thanks, posted there. How would you like me to edit this question? @RamNarasimhan